# Counterexample of the reciprocal of Langrage's theorem.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Lagrange's theorem states that if $G$ is a finite group, the order of every subgroup $H<G$ must verify that $|H| \mid |G|$ (the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$)

The reciprocal result is not true, but the only example I could find is the group of even permutations $A_4,$ which has order $12$ and does not have any subgroup of order $6.$

Is there any other 'easy' counterexample of this?

Comment: I think this the easiest example.

Comment: I know, actually i think that $A_4$ is the smallest group where you can find a counterexample, but I'm interested in any other one.

Comment: check this one,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103266/counterexamples-to-converse-to-lagranges-theorem-different-from-a-4

Comment: Oh wow, that was helpfull. Thank you.

Comment: yes indeed, is what @math commented before.