# Does Lagrange's theorem sometimes imply that there are subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If G is a group of order n, does Lagrange's theorem also imply that there *are* subgroups of orders dividing n?  That is if I have a group of order 15, are there *always* subgroups of order 1, 3, and 5?

Comment: I think you'll always be able to find a subgroup of order $1$ ;)

Comment: What you are asking about is the **converse** of Lagrange's Theorem. It is known to be false. See [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41731/742) on partial converses, [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/100933/742) on proving the converse is false, and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66451/742) about groups for which the converse *does* hold.

Comment: For cyclic groups the converse does hold. In general however, it does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest counterexample is that [$A_4$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/A4), the group of even permutations on 4 items, has 12 elements, but contains no subgroups of order 6.

I believe the general question of when an $mn$-group contains a subgroup of order $n$ is still an open research area. [Cauchy's theorem](http://enwp.org/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) guarantees that if $p$ is prime, then a group of order $pn$ contains an element of order $p$, and therefore a cyclic subgroup of order $p$. So for your example, every group of order 15 does contain subgroups of orders 3 and 5. (And, obviously, 1.)  As N.S. noted, the [Sylow theorems](http://enwp.org/Sylow_theorem) are important here.

[This page](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_having_subgroups_of_all_orders_dividing_the_group_order) discusses the issue in more detail, including some other circumstances when the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds.  I think [the Wikipedia article on Lagrange's theorem](http://enwp.org/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) also discusses the converse.

Answer (score 0):

No. It follows from Lagrange Theorem that $G$ has subgroups of order either 3 or 5, but you can't say which....

But in your case, Cauchy Theorem is what you need (or Sylow's theorems).

Comment: It does not follow from Lagrange's theorem that $G$ has subgroups of order either $3$ or $5$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why not? By Lagrange, an element of $G$ other than the identity has order $3$, $5$, or $15$. If $15$, then $G$ is cyclic, and there are subgroups of orders both $3$ and $15$. Else, etc. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andres: perhaps I should have said it does not follow _directly_ from Lagrange's theorem that $G$ has subgroups of order either $3$ or $5$. What I meant is that the statement of Lagrange's theorem doesn't have a logical form that immediately says anything about possible converses.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If $|G|=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot...\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$, it is an immediate consequence of Lagrange that $G$ has an element of order $p_1$ or $p_2$ or ... or $p_k$. Since this result is a simple Corollary to LT, I would say it follows from LT...