# Can the converse of Lagrange's Theorem hold for composite integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In general the converse to Lagrange's Theorem is false - $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

However, the converse holds for the set of primes - given a prime $p$ and a finite group $G$, if $p$ divides $|G|$, then there exists a subgroup of $G$ of order $p$. This is Cauchy's Theorem.

Indeed, this also holds for prime powers $p^k$.

Are the prime powers the maximal set for which the converse of Lagrange's Theorem holds? In other words, does there exists some composite integer $n>1$, not a prime power, such that for any finite group $G$, if $n$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$? Or is it the case that for any such $n$ one can construct a finite group $G$ with order divisible by $n$ yet with no subgroup of order $n$?

Comment: It holds for all powers of prime numbers.

Comment: Yes of course, I totally forgot that case. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Related; the converse of Lagrange holds for groups whose order is a [nilpotent numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67469/742). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66455/742).

Comment: I spent some time thinking about this, but now i see that I answered it myself 10 years ago!